# VBA Word - changing decimal separator

Tags: vba, ms-word

Some people around me using national localization in windows/office. Unfortunately this leads to situation where my macros fail to do simple math as they using comma for decimal position and the pov-ray files, that I editing, use comma only for list separator and point for decimal one. I know that in Excel one can override system decimal separator using

```
With Application.
    .DecimalSeparator = "."
    .ThousandsSeparator = ","
    .UseSystemSeparators = False
End With
```

There is however no such property of Application like DecimalSeparator in MS Word. Is there in MS Word a simple way to overwrite system separator for the time a macros is running? Or do I need to go hard way and replace them during reading of povray files?

Comment: I couldn't find anything like that. I checked `Application, Global` and `Options` properties but nothing similar there. But there could be any solution when using System settings or API- no idea...

Comment: You can determine the current values from the `Application.International` property - e.g. `Debug.Print Application.International(wdDecimalSeparator)` See the `wdInternationalIndex` enum [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191922.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being not very patient I did it the "harder way". I declared public variable

```
Public strDecimal As String
```

and then on the beginning of main sub I set its value with:

```
strDecimal = Application.International(wdDecimalSeparator)
```

Then in source I replaced all read-ins like

```
CDbl(strShort(5))
```

with

```
CDbl(Replace(strShort(5), ".", strDecimal))
```

and all write-outs like

```
Selection.TypeText Text:=CStr(Int(1000 * bondRadius) / 1000)
```

with

```
Selection.TypeText Text:=CStr(Replace(Int(1000 * bondRadius) / 1000, strDecimal, "."))
```

It's not as elegant as overwriting systems setting but it took me not too much time and it works for me. If anyone can see reason, why it should on occasion fail, please leave some comments.

I'll play a bit with info from barrowc's comment (thanx) to see if it's read only or read-write value.

Answer (score -2):

```
sub ReplaceCommabetweenDigits(sData as String)

 sData = Replace(sData, "0,0", "0.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,1", "0.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,2", "0.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,3", "0.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,4", "0.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,5", "0.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,6", "0.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,7", "0.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,8", "0.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "0,9", "0.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,0", "1.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,1", "1.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,2", "1.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,3", "1.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,4", "1.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,5", "1.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,6", "1.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,7", "1.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,8", "1.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "1,9", "1.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,0", "2.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,1", "2.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,2", "2.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,3", "2.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,4", "2.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,5", "2.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,6", "2.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,7", "2.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,8", "2.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "2,9", "2.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,0", "3.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,1", "3.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,2", "3.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,3", "3.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,4", "3.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,5", "3.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,6", "3.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,7", "3.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,8", "3.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "3,9", "3.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,0", "4.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,1", "4.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,2", "4.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,3", "4.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,4", "4.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,5", "4.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,6", "4.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,7", "4.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,8", "4.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "4,9", "4.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,0", "5.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,1", "5.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,2", "5.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,3", "5.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,4", "5.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,5", "5.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,6", "5.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,7", "5.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,8", "5.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "5,9", "5.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,0", "6.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,1", "6.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,2", "6.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,3", "6.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,4", "6.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,5", "6.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,6", "6.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,7", "6.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,8", "6.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "6,9", "6.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,0", "7.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,1", "7.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,2", "7.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,3", "7.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,4", "7.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,5", "7.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,6", "7.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,7", "7.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,8", "7.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "7,9", "7.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,0", "8.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,1", "8.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,2", "8.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,3", "8.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,4", "8.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,5", "8.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,6", "8.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,7", "8.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,8", "8.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,9", "8.9")
sData = Replace(sData, "8,0", "8.0")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,1", "9.1")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,2", "9.2")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,3", "9.3")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,4", "9.4")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,5", "9.5")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,6", "9.6")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,7", "9.7")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,8", "9.8")
sData = Replace(sData, "9,9", "9.9")


End sub
```