# Temporarily CHANGE decimal and thousands separator in Word for a specific document

Tags: vba, windows-10, ms-word, word-2013

Sometimes I need to write invoices in English, using the dot as decimal and the comma as thousands separator. Unlike Excel, Word itself doesn't offer an option to change this, it solely relies on the appropriate and systemwide Windows setting.

Changing and reverting this setting manually every time I need to write an invoice in English is not really an option. I'm aware that a similar question has already been asked at [VBA Word - changing decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16191557/9513810) but the search/replace solution provided there is not really a solution (and "solves" a different problem). I don't need to do any calculation in the document, the only matter is just the correct alignment at the position of the decimal tab.

I have found that the relevant properties can be read with `Application.International(wdDecimalSeparator)` and `Application.International(wdThousandsSeparator)` e.g.:

```
Sub Show_Limiters()
    MsgBox "Decimal: " & Application.International(wdDecimalSeparator) & vbCrLf & _
    "Thousand: " & Application.International(wdThousandsSeparator)
End Sub
```

But I have not found any hint yet how to **SET/CHANGE** these properties.

So is it possible to temporarily change these properties with a VBA macro upon opening an existing or creating a new document (and reset them again to the default value upon closing it)? If so, how? ;) Most likely I'm just too noobish in terms of VBA to figure that out myself. :(

If this is not possible: Is there any way to temporarily change the systemwide Windows setting instead (probably with a combination of VBA and VBScript)?

Any help is most appreciated. And yes, I know that I could use a right tab instead of the decimal tab, but this is just a weak workaround.

Windows 10 Pro, Office Pro Plus 2013 (German)

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to change those settings? Can't you just use find and replace somehow?

Comment: Used to be able to do it using System.PrivateProfileString to change the Registry. I can change the Registry, but Word isn't "seeing" it...

Comment: @CSS: As I said, when I write an invoice in English (e.g. to a customer in the UK), I need to use the dot (instead of the comma) as decimal separator. And if I do that, the numbers are not properly aligned at the decimal tab. Plus that I'm creating a new invoice anyway, what exactly should I find and replace...?

Comment: @Cindy: I did have the idea of a registry hack already as well, somewhere I saw a post/article which explained how to change registry keys with Word VBA. But I was also afraid that Word might not "see" the change (probably reboot required?). I'll test that manually first - should it work, then I may ask you for your help again. ;) But the properties ``Application.International(wdDecimalSeparator)`` and ``Application.International(wdThousandsSeparator)`` can't be changed, right?

Comment: They can be changed, but not the way you show it...

Comment: I didn't show any way at all how to change (but just how to read) them. Would you mind to explain how they can be changed (as this is the subject of this post)? ;)

Comment: I just tested changing the registry settings ``HKCU\Control Panel\International\sDecimal`` and ``HKCU\Control Panel\International\sThousand``: they **ARE** seen by Word - at least the macro above does show the changed values instantly. Unfortunately, it requires a restart of Word until any document does respect them. I have no clue if there is any VBA command that does a sort of "refresh" without restarting Word.

Comment: I do not remember whether Word has an option to change those settings. Only Excel has those options.

Comment: As I wrote above: "Unlike Excel, Word itself doesn't offer an option to change this [...]". If Word would have such an option, this topic wouldn't exist. ;)

Comment: @myfxp VBA can't change those settings directly, mainly since they're read only in VBA. You can change the system settings programmatically. While this can be done technically through VBA, it really just makes Win32 calls and isn't in the scope of VBA. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2. Using a .NET application with Word would be relatively easy, if not awkward. My suggestion would be keep looking at VBA and maybe change your approach.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @ForEachLoop, but I'm afraid what you're suggesting is way beyond my capabilities. But anyway, which approach ever we may take, one problem will most likely remain: although Word will "see" the changed system setting, the open document doesn't "respect" it - a restart of Word is required (see my comment above). Unless there is a way to do a sort of "refresh" with some VBA command and without restarting Word, but nobody did mention such a command yet.

Comment: How to change the (registry) setting, seems to be relatively easy, at least I found several ways to do it, e.g. https://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html (though I didn't test it yet, as it won't solve the "Word restart requirement" either).